# A good static site generator for Windows / .NET? (similar to Pelican, Jekyll, etc.)

Tags: html, .net, razor, web

I'm currently building a static website template and I need a site generator to generate the templates HTML files (I don't want to copy and paste the common parts but rather have them only at one place)

Is there a good static website generator for Windows / .NET developers? (analog to Pelican, Jekyll, etc.)

I've found [Pretzel by Code52](https://github.com/Code52/pretzel) but the Github page seems rather abandoned (last change 1 year ago).

Is there any alternative for Windows? Preferably .NET based and using the Razor engine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pretzel and graze are the only two I know of:

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/graze-static-site-generator-using-razor/

Comment: Thx, I ended up using Pretzel after all, since it is pretty much Jekyll for .NET and I plan to switch to Linux as a working environment.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question, but for completeness I'll add http://wyam.io (open source - code at https://github.com/Wyamio/Wyam). It satisfies the .NET and Razor requirements (it actually uses a modified version of the Razor engine from ASP.NET v5) and is built on a modular "pipeline" concept (similar to the excellent Metalsmith JS generator).

Full disclosure - I am the developer of Wyam.

Comment: There is no problem in answering old questions, if you are going to add useful information. People stop at old answers all the time. In fact, StackOverflow is not a place to solve your problem and go away, is more like an enourmous database of tutorials on how to do small tasks or solve small problems.

Comment: Just to add an update, wyam has been archived on github and the successor is now called Statiq https://statiq.dev/web/

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at using champ for a project that has similar requirements:

https://github.com/lukevenediger/champ

Comment: No commits after April 2014 - probably discontinued

Comment: I'm not sure "discontinued" is the right word (e.g. as used to describe the problem with mixture.io). It's open source; the code's still available and someone could always fork it.

Comment: I agree, its not maintained by the original author, there is a fork with some changes: https://github.com/tysonmatanich/champ

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried it, but [Mixture](http://mixture.io/) seems the best one for me.

#### UPDATE: Mixture is now discontinued.

Comment: This seems to be discontinued now.

Comment: Yes. What should I do? Delete the answer?

Comment: Nope, the edit is fine. I was on the lookout for one last night and going through all the links and mixture seemed great from what I learnt about it. Sad it's not there any more. In such cases, I feel it would help to notify the future users/lurkers.

Comment: Thank you for telling me and everybody, Nanda. You could have edited my answer yourself, I wouldn't be offended by it.

Comment: It's unfortunate they closed the project and didn't choose to open source it near the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another static site generator can be found here:
http://www.hilbert.dk/thomas/pub/dev/StaticSiteGenerator/

Code located here:
https://bitbucket.org/hilbert/staticsitegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Lektor: https://www.getlektor.com

Web based gui like WordPress to write content. Good to setup for someone who is not a developer but enough customizability under the hood for a developer to configure